# Test reactive forms to be void when reset

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I am currently working on a project made with Angular13, and since there are no more work to do this week, I decided to do some unit testing using Jest in order to improve my coding skills.

In this case, I want to test a method reset(), which does, as his name says, resets the form, but I can not find the way to test that.

I provide some code:

**component.ts**

```
this.myForm= this.fb.group({
      a: new FormControl(),
      b: new FormControl(),
      c: new FormControl(),
    });

// Clean form
  resetForm() {
    this.myForm.get('a')?.reset();
    this.myForm.get('b')?.reset();
    this.myForm.get('c')?.reset();
  }
```

(I know you can reset all the form with `this.myForm.reset`, but I simplified the code snippet because I just want to reset some specific fields, not all the form)

**component.spec.ts**

```
it('resets form', () => {
    const form = component.myForm;
    component.resetForm()
    expect(form.get('a')).toBe('')
    expect(form.get('b')).toBe('')
    expect(form.get('c')).toBe('')
  })
```

Am I doing it properly? What is supposed to be the value of the field when it has been reset?

**[UPDATE]**

```
it('reset form', () => {
    const form = component.myForm;
    form.markAllAsTouched()
    form.markAsDirty()
    component.resetForm()
    form.markAsUntouched()
    form.markAsPristine()


    expect(form.get('a')).toBe(null)
    expect(form.get('b')).toBe(null)
    expect(form.get('c')).toBe(null)
  })
```

Answer (score 0):

> What is supposed to be the value of the field when it has been reset?

That comes down to your implementation/initialization of the form.
From the [docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset):

> (`form.reset()`) Resets the FormGroup, marks all descendants **pristine** and **untouched** and sets the value of all descendants to their **default values**, or **null** if no defaults were provided.

In order to test your method you should set the form as dirty and touched, as well as patching it some value.
Then, once that's done, check if the fields are **pristine**, **untouched** and `null` (given that your example holds no default value).

Comment: I have updated the question (still not working because what I did its not correct). Could you check that please?